# c++11 about rvalue reference

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int&& move(int&& t) {
    return static_cast<int &&>(t);
}

int main() {
    move(5) = 10;//why error? 

    return 0;
}
```

Error

```
prog.cpp:9:13: error: using xvalue (rvalue reference) as lvalue
```

[Here's the complete sample](http://ideone.com/qWx993)

I can not understand. Does not move function return a rvalue reference?

Comment: You can't "move" an integer, even if you have an r-value reference to it. And you certainly can't assign *to* an integer literal.

Comment: Suggesting to study all the terms in the error message

Comment: error:using xvalue(rvalue reference) as lvalue

Comment: @Cameron, I'm thinking the OP is expecting this to happen: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ceaa01a9e7295059

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [What are rvalues, lvalues, xvalues, glvalues, and prvalues?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601602/what-are-rvalues-lvalues-xvalues-glvalues-and-prvalues)

Comment: @user2178911 Take a serious look: `move(5) = 10;` What should this achieve actually? Telling `5` that it has to be `10` now, or the other way round?!?

Comment: @user2178911: Yes, your move function does return an rvalue reference. Even the error message confirms that. So what? Rvalue references are never allowed on the left-hand side of the built-in assignmenet operator. This is what the compiler is telling you.

Comment: @AndreyT http://ideone.com/Trw1AA

Comment: @user2178911: Well, *named* revalue reference is an lvalue. *Unnamed* rvalue reference is not an lvalue. In your original code you are using an unnamed rvalue referce, which is the key detail that makes it different.

Answer (score 2):

§ 3.10

From how I interpret the standard, `lvalue`s, `xvalue`s and `prvalue`s are mutually exclusive.

> Every expression belongs to exactly one of the fundamental
>   classifications in this taxonomy: lvalue, xvalue, or prvalue.

A literal such as `5` is a `prvalue`.

> — A prvalue (“pure” rvalue) is an rvalue that is not an xvalue. [
>   Example: The result of calling a function whose return type is not a
>   reference is a prvalue. The value of a literal such as 12, 7.3e5, or
>   true is also a prvalue. — end example ]

And in your "move" function, you get an `xvalue` because:

> [ Example: The result of calling a function whose return type is an
>   rvalue reference is an xvalue. — end example ]

As for why your assignment fails, see:

> 5 An lvalue for an object is necessary in order to modify the object
>   except that an rvalue of class type can also be used to modify its
>   referent under certain circumstances. [ Example: a member function
>   called for aobject (9.3) can modify the object. — end example ]

[cppreference's page on assigment operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_assignment) puts this in plainer language.

> The direct assignment operator expects a modifiable lvalue as its left
>   operand and an rvalue expression or a braced-init-list (since C++11)
>   as its right operand, and returns an lvalue identifying the left
>   operand after modification.

So finally:

```
       move(5) =      10
xvalue ^      prvalue ^
```

Reference:
[Value categories](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category)